# What does LibGDX's mesh.getVerticies output?

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, mesh

I am working on a 3D LibGDX project, and am trying to manipulate the vertices of a 3D model. I have the model loading, and I have this as my code:

```
Model plain = assets.get("plain.g3db", Model.class);
for(Mesh m : plain.meshes){
    float[] t = m.getVertices(new float[m.getMaxVertices()]);
    float[] newVerticies = new float[m.getMaxVertices()];
    for(int i = 0; i < t.length-1; i++){
        newVerticies[i] = t[i];
        System.out.println("X: " + t[i] + " " + i);
        newVerticies[i] = t[i];
        System.out.println("Y: " + t[i++] + " " + i);
        newVerticies[i] = random.nextInt(1-0) + 0;
        System.out.println("Z: " + t[i++] + " " + i);
        newVerticies[i] = t[i];
        System.out.println("R: " + t[i++]);
        newVerticies[i] = t[i];
        System.out.println("G: " + t[i++]);
        newVerticies[i] = t[i];
        System.out.println("B: " + t[i++]);
        newVerticies[i] = t[i];
        System.out.println("A: " + t[i++]);
    }
    m.setVertices(newVerticies);
}
```

That does not work how I want it to, but I can at least see the model. If I comment out these lines:

```
newVerticies[i] = t[i];
System.out.println("R: " + t[i++]);
newVerticies[i] = t[i];
System.out.println("G: " + t[i++]);
newVerticies[i] = t[i];
System.out.println("B: " + t[i++]);
newVerticies[i] = t[i];
System.out.println("A: " + t[i++]);
```

I just get a black screen. Even if I move around, I see nothing. What I want to know, is what exactly `float[] t = m.getVertices(new float[m.getMaxVertices()]);` outputs. How does the output correspond to the model? How can I make the Y value random within a range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mesh data is organized into VertexAttributes. These always include position, but can also include color, texture coordinates, normals, etc. For example, a mesh with a texture might have the following:

- A Position VertexAttribute of size 3 for X, Y, and Z (it's possible to have a 2D mesh where the position attribute has only 2)
- A TextureCooridantes VertexAttribute of size 2 for U and V
- A Normal VertexAttribute with size 3 for X, Y, and Z

So the float array you get with `mesh.getVertices()` would be this set of 8 floats for each vertex, one after the other.

If you loaded your Mesh from a model file rather than constructing it manually, you might not be sure of what VertexAttribute setup it has, so you need to inspect it to find out what the offset of the attribute you want is:

```
int positionOffset = mesh.getVertexAttributes().getOffset(Usage.Position);
int yOffset = positionOffset + 1; //skip X
int vertexSize = mesh.getVertexSize() / 4; //divide to convert bytes to floats
```

Now if you wanted to change Y, you would loop through the vertices something like this:

```
//this is how to get the properly sized mesh:
float[] vertices = new float[mesh.getNumVertices() * mesh.getVertexSize() / 4];
mesh.getVertices(vertices);

for (int i = yOffset; i < vertices.length; i += vertexSize){
    vertices[i] += someValue;
}
mesh.setVertices(vertices);
```

The indices indicate groups of three vertices that make up the triangles of the mesh. If there are vertices on your mesh that are the same on multiple triangles, they might appear in the vertices list only once. This typically happens on soft-shaded vertices of a mesh, since the UV and normal will be the same for all the adjacent triangles touching that vertex.